# Getting the selected value from a drop down list and multiplying it by value in sql table in PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble trying to get a value from a drop-down list and multiplying the value by a number in the 'ticket' table. I've been trying to implement this calculation in both PHP and javascript but having no luck :(

Here is the form (which is returned to the homepage by AJAX):

```
$pcSearch = $_POST['postcodeSearch'];

$postCodeSQL = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE locationID IN (SELECT locationID FROM location WHERE postCode LIKE '$pcSearch') ";

$postCoderesult = mysql_query($postCodeSQL) or die(mysql_error());

 while ($pcRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($postCoderesult)) {
        $venue = $pcRow['venue'];
        $ticketPrice = $pcRow['tPrice'];
        $date = $pcRow['date'];
        $time= $pcRow['time'];

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>$venue</td>\n";
    echo "<td>&pound$ticketPrice</td>\n";
    echo "<td><form id=\"quantity\" method=\"post\" name=\"ticketQuantity\">
                 <select name =\"showQuantity\" id=\"showQuantity\" class =\"showQuantity\" >
                    <option value=\"1\">1</option>                                      
                    <option value=\"2\">2</option>
                    <option value=\"3\">3</option>
                    <option value=\"4\">4</option>
                    <option value=\"5\">5</option>
                 </select>
              </form>
          </td>\n";
    echo "<td>$date</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$time</td>\n";

    echo "<td><form name=\"buyTicket\" class=\"buyTicket\" id=\"buyTicket\" > 
                  <input type= \"button\" id= \"buyMe\" class= \"buyMe\" value= \"Buy\" name=\"buyMe\"> 
              </form> 
          </td>\n";
   echo "</tr>\n";

}
```

Basically, what I wanting to do is when a user clicks and choose the quantity of tickets they want i.e. 3, this number will be multiplied by the price of the ticket ('tPrice'). Is there a way of getting both these values and multiplying them together in PHP?

I've tried adding jQuery to listen for the button click function but to no avail...I even tried debugging it but for some strange reason it won't output the alert:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buyMe").click(function() {
    alert('click');
   });
});
```

However if I were to use jQuery, how would I even get the value of 'tPrice' from the form?

Thanks very much for any help :)

Comment: You really really REALLY need to read up about [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s and eliminate your bad case of leaning-toothpick syndrome.

Comment: also your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: Is this what you need ?: parseInt(document.getElementById('showQuantity').value)
* parseFloat(document.getElementById('showQuantity').parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.innerHTML.substr(1));

Comment: Ah I see...so using '\' before the "" is what may be causing a problem? and use HEREDOC to escape the quotes?

Comment: @Cfreak...yeah I'm aware of this, i'll be using prepared statements later.

Comment: Yes or you use Single Quotes.

Comment: @user1150525: There seems to be a problem with the syntax with what you've written, I can't see where though?

Comment: Here is the code again: parseInt(document.getElementById('showQuantity').value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById('showQuantity').parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.innerHTML.substr(1));     .... it seems that the word "previousSibling" isn't ok? Just delete it and write it again.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The first thing i would do is add a class to the ticket price `td` :</strike>

```
echo "<td class=\"ticketPrice\">&pound$ticketPrice</td>\n";
```

What that does it make it a lot easier to get the price using jQuery.

So now .. you can do this :

```
$(".buyMe").click(function() {
    var priceForOne = $(this).siblings('.ticketPrice').text().substr(1);
});
```

Infact as you have access to the source of the HTML a better way would probably using `data()` :

```
echo '<input type="button" class="buyMe" value="Buy" data-ticket-price="'.$ticketPrice.'"/>';
```

then you can change your click to be :

```
$(".buyMe").click(function() {
    var priceForOne = $(this).data('ticketPrice');
});
```

A couple of other points ..

remove the `id` attribute from here :

```
<input type= \"button\" id= \"buyMe\" class= \"buyMe\" value= \"Buy\" name=\"buyMe\">
```

there is no need for a form around the select list as its doing nothing ... similarly the form around the button is doing nothing either !

### Updated

The `click` method won't work for DOM elements added after the document has been loaded (ie via AJAX) ... you need to use the `on()` method :

```
$(document).on('click','.buyMe',function() {
// handle the click here
});
```

the `$(document)` above needs to be a parent element of the `buyMe` element and present on the DOM at load, in your case you could replace `$(document)` with `$('#idOfYourTable')`

[Docs for data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [Docs for on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Another way would be document.getElementById('showQuantity').parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling

Comment: @ManseUK: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to implement this and see if it works. The only problem is, the button doesn't seem to respond to the jQuery...that's why I have added an alert function to kind-of debug it but it won't display the alert :s

Comment: @TimJohnstone updated my answer further ... check out the on() method

Comment: Smashing! I haven't seen this on() function before :)

Comment: @TimJohnstone note its jQuery 1.7 and onwards ... investigate `delegate()` or `live()` if using older versions

Comment: cool! that $(document).on() function is working (though i've only added an alert() to debug it). How do you call a value from a table column in JS/jQuery? Because the price for each ticket is set in my database and im wanting to pull that value out depending on the ticketID

Comment: something along the lines of: $ticketPrice = ['tPrice'].text()?

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a non-existent class name instead of the id. Change `.buyme` to `#buyme`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buyMe").click(function() {
    alert('click');
   });
});
```

**Edit** missed that the class is on there too. However since you're just referencing a single element you should use the ID anyway.

Comment: I have referenced a class: class= \"buyMe\" (this is located in the <input type..> line.